# Como fazer um input em JS com um programa js puro sem html

Tags: javascript

Estou treinando essa parte de classes e para deixa-las dinâmicas é necessário que aconteça algum input enquanto o programa roda. Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso usando puramente o JS e sem ser em uma página HTML.

Comment: Depende de onde está rodando. Num browser, ou electron (que é browser da mesma forma) existe o [prompt](https://caniuse.com/?search=prompt), (abra o console e digite `prompt('digite algo');` e enter, para testar - o valor retornado é a string digitada). Se for  algo como o node, tem maneiras variadas de entrar com argumentos. Precisaria detalhar melhor o cenário. Seja como for, todo ambiente básico (console, browser e outros) costuma ter tudo sobre I/O nativo na documentação básica. O próprio console ja é input, você pode digitar `nomedasuafuncao(valoresvariados)` que já é um modo de testar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sem o HTML não achei essa solução, mas acredito que você queira é controlar os eventos a partir do javascript e ler as informações de input que o usuário digita.

Se você quiser essa é a solução para isso:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access a Text Field</h3>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="Some text...">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to get the text in the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

O uso de inputs não é um recurso nativo do JavaScript. Então é preciso instalar a biblioteca readline-sync através do NPM, gerenciador de pacotes do Node, através do comando npm install readline-sync e depois importá-la para o seu código.

Exemplo (rode esse código):

```
const entradaDados = require('readline-sync');

console.log('Olá! Qual é o seu nome?\n\n');

let nome = entradaDados.question("Digite o seu nome: ");

console.log("\n\nOlá "+nome+".\n\n");

console.log("Um abraço, André!");
```